# React: Lag observed when array is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks, onchange

I'm having a problem on inputs than want to change in array, there is a lot of lag/delay when typing in inputs when this array  have more than 8 arraylists, i make this code below to simple reproduce what's happen with my code.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Inputs from './Inputs'

function App() {

  const [ array, setArray ] = useState([
    ["John",'30','ttt'],
    ["Smith",'20','ttt'],
    ["Thiago",'40','ttt'],
    ["Jake",'30','ttt'],
    ["Fer",'41','ttt'],
    ["Fred",'23','ttt'],
    ["Otto",'55','ttt'],
    ["Gago",'21','ttt'],
    ["Higor",'15','ttt'],
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Inputs array={array} setArray={setArray} />
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => {
          
          /** add More arrays */
          setArray(array=> [...array, ['','','']])

        }}>add more</button>
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => console.log("Send array to DB")}>Send array to DB</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Inputs.js

```
import './App.css';
import React,{ useEffect } from 'react';

function Inputs(props) {

const { array, setArray } = props

const handleInputChange = (e, index, position2) => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    const list = [...array];
    list[index][position2] = value;
    setArray(list);   
};

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(array)
},[array])

  return (
    array.map((item, index) => {
        return (<div key={index}>
            
            <input 
                value={item[0]}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    handleInputChange(e,index,0)
                }}
            />
            <input 
                value={item[1]}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    handleInputChange(e,index,1)
                }}
            />
            <input 
                value={item[2]}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    handleInputChange(e,index,2)
                }}
            />
        </div>)
    })
  );
}

export default Inputs;
```

I don't find another option to change value in this array, and each type in inputs are creating every arrays again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider maintaining separate states for all the inputs instead of creating a common state.

A better alternative to this will be to create a pure component that can be used for rendering all the inputs - Then you will just have to pass the value and onChange callback.

Comment: This solved my problem, creating another JS file only for inputs, then each inputs have your unique useState. It works, thanks.

Comment: Great!! Happy Coding!